# SQL-Server 2012 Subtracting Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some counts that get periodically recorded into SQL and I'm trying to find out the difference between the start count and the final count.

**Raw Data Below**

[image]

This table has around 30 columns but they are the more of the same just different counts.

I want to take the min and max row for a time period based on user input from an SQL report I can filter out the data with the code below. (I can also filter it into two different tables, one with min, and one with max if that is easier.)

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM #tempTable 
     WHERE TableIndex = (SELECT min(TableIndex) FROM #tempTable)
        or TableIndex = (SELECT max(TableIndex) FROM #tempTable)
```

**Filtered Data Below**
[image]

The end goal is the difference between these two rows, I would then give that data to an SQL report to display a bar graph.

I've seen solutions but they seemed overly complex for what I'm trying to do and I would need to define each column I'm subtracting vs using *. Some of the tables have a couple hundred columns.

Comment: Is TableIndex unique (e.g. primary key)?

Comment: Couldn't you do the subtraction in the report?

Comment: @jarlh yes it is

Comment: @MJH I'm not sure that is an angle I have not looked at yet but will see what I can find.

Comment: Will the table schemas be consistent for the first two columns but may contain any number of columns (but all defined as INTs) thereafter?

Comment: @mjh first two columns will always be the same and yes you are correct the number of columns after the first two will change per table and there are 6 tables atm.

Answer (score 0):

How about joining these together?

```
 SELECT tt.*, ttm.*
 FROM #tempTable tt
      (SELECT min(TableIndex) as minti, max(TableIndx) as maxti
       FROM #tempTable
      ) ttm
      ON ttmTableIndex IN (ttm.minti, ttm.maxti);
```

You can then do whatever arithmetic operations you like with the values in the same row.

Personally, I would find it easier to just put the two rows into a spreadsheet and subtract the values using a formula.

Comment: That might work let me take a look at it. As for the spreadsheet this is meant to be an automatic process that they can see a report from and that's pretty much it. I would need another application to get the data from SQL to a spreadsheet and then into some sort report.